# Using onclick colour changer to alter paragraph text colour but only for parent paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have a 3 column document, at the footer of each column is a colour changer that changes the paragraph text colour, I am sure this is fairly simple, but it should only change the colour of the parent div, at the moment the code changes all para's on the page.

Code:

```
$('a.text_blue').click(function() {
    $('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('blue_text');   
});
$('a.text_red').click(function() {
    $('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('red_text');    
});
$('a.text_black').click(function() {
    $('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('black_text');  
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="colour_changer">
        <a href="#" class="text_blue"></a>
        <a href="#" class="text_red"></a>
        <a href="#" class="text_black"></a>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need to see CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: css would help, yes, simply add `.parent();`

Comment: "it should only change the colour of the parent div"... then why are you targeting `p` elements?

Comment: Sorry it is a single para within the parent div, I meant to say it should change the text colour of the p element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from your clarification comment, you can use `siblings` to get the `p` elements that are siblings of the `a` elements. Since by the sound of it they share a parent, this should work:

```
$('a.text_blue').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('blue_text');   
});
```

If you have reduced your markup for the question, and they are not really siblings, you can use `parent` to go up to the `div`, and then `find` to get the descendent `p` elements:

```
$('a.text_blue').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('blue_text');   
});
```

---

On a side note, you could rewrite your code so you don't have to bind a separate event handler to each `a` element. You could do something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-class="blue-text"></a>
```

And then delegate the event handler:

```
$(".color_changer").on("click", "a", function() {
    $(this).parent().find("p").removeAttr("class").addClass($(this).data("class"));
});
```

---

**Update**

Now that you've posted a link to your code, I can give you a definitive answer! The `p` element you need to target is a sibling of the parent `div`:

```
$('a.text_blue').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('blue_text');   
});
```

And since you're using jQuery 1.6, you can still benefit from event delegation with the `delegate` method:

```
$(".color_changer").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('p').removeAttr("class").addClass($(this).data("class"));
});
```

Comment: love the side note, turns 9~ lines into 3

Comment: Thank you, the first part of the answer makes the most sense to me  I'm still having a problem with the selector somewhere, I uploaded the code here: http://dev.slackwise.org.uk/test/ (also I am using jQuery 1.6 so .on events are not available).

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you're reffering to all the paragraphs in the page.
Give the paragraph you want an id and just choose

```
   $('#yourparagraph').removeAttr('class').addClass('red_text');
```

Or you can use class

```
     $('.yourclass').removeAttr('class').addClass('red_text');
```

Depends on your needs.

However your problem is not very clear, this could be different then what you want because i saw no

tags in your code, but in general you have to tell jQuery which elemnt you want your code to apply on. when simple write p tag, it will effect the entire page.

Comment: rather than using IDs to reference things why not use parent/child relationship :)

Comment: Could be the better solution i don't know, i'm kind of an efficiency freak i always afraid to use extra methods :)

Comment: Yes that is what I need to do, the colour changer is repeated inside every paragraph so if I did use id's I would have to write 3 times as much jquery to target the elements. Unfortunately $('p').removeAttr('class').parent().addClass('blue_text'); is not working.

Comment: use class then... i revised answer

Answer (score 0):

In your JS, you're binding your on click event to all paragraphs with

```
$('p').removeAttr('class').addClass('red_text');
```

This is grabbing every p element on the page (so, every p in every div).

Give each parent div an id, then change your event handler to change only the pargraphs in the parent div, so, say for example you gave the 3 divs id's of #div_1, #div_2, and #div_3...

```
$("#div_1 p").removAttr('class').addClass('red_text');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p')
```

is shorthand for referencing *every* <p> tag on the page.

You should give the element you want to modify an id attribute like so

```
<p id="iWantThisToChangeColors">
```

and modify your code to reference just that id, like so:

```
$('a.text_blue').click(function() {
     $('#iWantThisToChangeColors').removeAttr('class').addClass('blue_text');   
});
```

There are much more efficient ways to change something simple like the color of text in an element, as well as echo out color-changer links, but this will do it for you without having to modify your current code too much.